# MySQL select distinct values based on specific field

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

hi i have a table with 6 columns, amongst them the is a column called user_id which has many occurances in the table and also a column i.e laptops where it references the laptops that a user has brought for some action. This also have many occurances in the table.

```
ID  DATE        LAPTOP    USER_ID
1   1/1/2014    Acer      10
2   1/1/2014    Toshiba   2
3   1/1/2014    HP        5
4   1/1/2014    Acer      5
5   1/1/2014    Toshiba   5
6   1/1/2014    HP        2
7   2/1/2014    Lenovo    2
8   2/1/2014    Acer      10
9   2/1/2014    HP        2
10  2/1/2014    HP        5
```

i need to select the distinct laptop occurences for each user_id and not generally the distinct occurances frm the table so the desired result would be

```
LAPTOP    USER_ID
Acer      10
Toshiba   2
HP        2
Lenovo    2
HP        5
Acer      5
Toshiba   5
```

whatever i ve tried seems to be far from the desired result so far

Comment: Can you show us the SQL that you tried?

Comment: `DISTINCT` and `CONCAT` can be a good start.

Comment: the most i could get was by using select distinct laptop from mytable groupby user_id and the result was far away from the expected

Comment: Wouldn't`select distinct laptop, user_id from table`give you the desired result?

Comment: no, because i don't want distinct user_id s i want for each "set" or user_ids to get the distinct values.. for instance like in the example user_id is displayed 3 times, with 3 distinct laptop values

Comment: And that is exactly what you would get, distinct combinations of laptop and user_id. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/340bc6/2

Comment: @nikolas jpw's solution will work too, it will select distinct combination of `laptop, user_id`

Comment: @jpw i had thought of this but was so confident that this wouldn't work, that i guess i probably hand't tried.. but it does seem to do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT LAPTOP, USER_ID FROM Table1 GROUP BY LAPTOP, USER_ID;
```

just to make the answer as complete as possible, I am adding jpw's solution that is a comment above.

```
SELECT DISTINCT laptop, user_id FROM table
```

Here's a `GROUP BY` [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0131/1)

Here's jpw's `DISTINCT` [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/340bc6/2)

Comment: this workds as well..i guess it wasn't so complicated as initially thought...thank you very much